# Display datetime in actionscript with no timezone or daylight savings time changes?

Tags: datetime, actionscript, timezone

In actionscript I am trying to format datetime fields coming in from a webservice call which takes into account the timezone and daylight savings time.  Basically we need to display times for events, here in our TZ at the time it will be on that day.  The following function works for timezones but we recently found that all of the upcoming times after the daylight savings time are being shifted an hour forward.

Is there a better way to handle this?

```
public function getTimeZoneFix(fixDate:Date):Date {
     var GMTHour:Number = 4; // our timzone offset
     var gmtDate:Date = new Date(fixDate);
     var hourOffset:Number = gmtDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60 - GMTHour;
     gmtDate.setHours(gmtDate.getHours() + hourOffset );
     return gmtDate;             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the following:
http://thanksmister.com/2011/10/06/determining-local-timezone-in-actionscript-air-flex-as3/

It may help.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as correct because it is probably as close as you can get.  I pretty much gave up on this and we ended up passing the date as a string from the server because, as you can see, doing this on the client is a lot of work and easy to get wrong.